# Linux permissions base conversion

Tags: linux, perl, cgi

I have a cgi script where I need to be able to parse linux file permissions.  The problem is that if a permission comes as "764" it is treated as a base 10 scalar in perl.  In other words it is represented as 1374 in octal while it is meant to represent 764 in octal.  I am not sure what conversion routine to call to say, take a var as a string and convert it to octal?  If you use sprintf, it will give the wrong result as it will return 1374, the octal conversion I showed above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you are looking for `oct` function

```
my $perm_o = '764';
my $perm_d = oct($perm_o);
print "$perm_d\n";
```

Output:

```
500
```

Refer to [`documentation`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html) for more details

Comment: Yes, thank you. I made my own in the mean time, but this is far better!

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just use `oct("764")` for this?

[The documentation actually suggests this exact use for it.](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html)